# UWP/XAML Content View with NavigationView

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need some help with getting conent and navigation to co-operate.
I currently have the following:

```
<Page
    x:Class="BS.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:local="using:BS"
    xmlns:mux="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:muxcontrols="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    RequestedTheme="Dark"   
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>

    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemBaseHighColor}"/>
                        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
                          BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
                          TintColor="#262626"
                          TintOpacity="0.8"
                          FallbackColor="#262626"/>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <mux:NavigationView IsSettingsVisible="False" 
                            PaneTitle=" BSM "                            
                            x:Name="NavView"                             
                            IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" 
                            PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal" 
                            AlwaysShowHeader="True"
                            Header="  "                            
                            Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDarkBackground}">

            <mux:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Page2" Margin="0, 2, 1, 0" Tag="New_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="OpenFile" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Open_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Save_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Calculator" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Calculator_Open" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <mux:NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="HItem" 
                                        Content="H" 
                                        Tag="H_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>
                <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="OItem" 
                                        Content="O" 
                                        Tag="O_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="BItem" 
                                        Content="B" 
                                        Tag="B_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="PItem" 
                                        Content="P" 
                                        Tag="BPayer_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="TsItem" 
                                        Content="TS" 
                                        Tag="Ts_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="PDItem" 
                                        Content="PD" 
                                        Tag="PD_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>
            </mux:NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
                <Button x:Name="ChangeUser" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Foreground="#b880fc" >
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Contact" Margin="8"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">      
                                    Change User
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        </mux:NavigationView>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock>
                Boo, im a text block
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>       
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Issue im having is that the Textblock is overlapping the navigation menu.
Im trying to get this to act as though it was the ContentPanel.
Im still very new to this, so still working things out as i go along. Would anyone mind helping me create a very basic "Hello World" Textbox that doesnt overlapt the navigation view button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your problem and you are making a very common mistake, the grid containing the textblock should be within the **NavigationView** control, in your case it is outside, try the following code.

```
 <--all code above is the same-->
<NavigationView.PaneFooter>
            <Button x:Name="ChangeUser" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Foreground="#b880fc" >
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Contact" Margin="8"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">      
                                Change User
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </NavigationView.PaneFooter>

                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock>
                        Boo, im a text block
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </mux:NavigationView>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```